# Ajax sending the request twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As I described in the title, ajax is sending two requests at the same time. This is happening only, when the "async" parameter is set to "true". When it is "false", then there is no problem.

I'm preventing the page to be reloaded by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
    showBusyIndicator();
    addTask();
    return false;
});
```

And this is the function addTask():

```
function addTask() {
let newTask = new Task(
    $("#taskSummary").val(),
    $("#taskDescription").val(),
    $("#taskDueTo").val()
);

$.ajax({
    url: apiHost + "/task/add/",
    headers: {
        "contentType": "application/json"
    },
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(newTask),
    complete: function (xhr) {
        hideBusyIndicator();
        if (xhr.status === 201) {
            closeAddTaskForm();
        } else {
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    },
});
}
```

Comment: Can you share Request Type of Both Requests from Chrome's Request Panel and API you are using is from same-orgin ?

Comment: Can we see the HTML please. And, is there any other invocations of the `addTask()` function anywhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - thanks to @Randy Casburn.

The invocation of addTask was both in `$(document).on('submit', 'form', function()`

and also in `<form onsubmit="addTask()">`